# How can I use XPath to get the previous sibling of the parent of the current node?

Tags: c#, html, .net, xml, xpath

The type of HTML structure I have is like

```
.
.
<a name="128312"></a>
<li>
  <ul class="post">
  .
  .
  </ul>
</li>
<a name="3849"></a>
<li>
  <ul class="post">
  .
  .
.
.
```

and from the context of a `node` being one of the `ul`s, I want to get the `name` of the nearest `a`, meaning the `name` of the parent's (`li`'s`) previous sibling, the equivalent of

```
node.ParentNode.PreviousSibling.GetAttributeValue("name", null)
```

except that

- I want to do it in XPath syntax
- The above query, for some reason, is returning a node whose contents are tabs and newlines between the `a` and `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from wing is partially correct. Use

```
parent::ul/preceding-sibling::a[1]/@name
```

It will get you the *first* `a` preceding the `ul` (as opposed to all of them). It will not check if it's also the first element. If that's a requirement, use

```
parent::ul/preceding-sibling::*[1][self::a]/@name
```